# Why does adding to a head tag in BeautifulSoup close the HTML tag immediately after the HEAD?

Tags: python, html, beautifulsoup

I am trying to write a web-page transformer that adds scripting and other tags to the HEAD of a webpage, as well as marking up the content in the BODY. I am using BeautifulSoup.  However, when I append elements to the HEAD tag, the output gets a  close tag added immediately after the , so the BODY becomes invisible.

Simplified code that adds a BASE tag to the HEAD and intends to boldface every third word in the text of the page is as follows:

```
def highlight(url):
    page = requests.get(url)
    page_soup = BeautifulSoup(page.content, 'html.parser')

    header = page_soup.find('head')

    base_string = "<base href=\"" + url + "\"/>"
    base_soup = BeautifulSoup(base_string,'html.parser')

    header.append(base_soup)

    para_list = page_soup.find_all('p')
    for para in para_list:
        result = ''
        sent_text = nltk.sent_tokenize(para.text)
        for sent in sent_text:
            tokens = nltk.word_tokenize(sent)
            position = 0
            for token in tokens:
                if position % 3 == 0:
                    text = BOLD(noun, sys1, number)
                    result += text
                else: 
                    result += noun + ' '
            position += 1
        para.replaceWith(BeautifulSoup(result, 'html.parser'))

    return page_soup
```

This does not boldface anything, since it doesn't find anything in the body since an  close tag is added right after the head. If I remove the `header.append(base_soup)`, the boldfacing works fine.

How to fix this?

Comment: Please could you provide the URL

Comment: `noun` is not defined. as is `BOLD`. besides this, i can't reproduce the behavior you describe